# HTTP 406 Response Code Check is breaking my Google App Engine/Python API

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, curl, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine API using Python and NDB working except for HTTP response code/error checking. I put in some code to handle 406 (to only accept json requests) and 400 errors (to prevent a user from leaving a required field blank) to the post function for one of my entities but now it seems to have broken my code. This is the code with the error checking included:

```
class Task_action(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        #Only allows a JSON, if not, then error
        if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:

            self.response.status = 406
            self.response.status_message = "Not Acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type"
            return
        new_task = Task(parent=PARENT_KEY,
                        name = self.request.get("task_name"),
                        hours = int(self.request.get("task_hours")),
                        id = self.request.get("task_name"))
        #has error code, since name and hours is required

        if name:
            new_task.name = name
        else:
            self.response.status = 400
            self.response.status_message = "Invalid request, task name is Required."
            if hours:
                new_task.hours = hours
            else:
                self.response.status = 400
                self.response.status_message = "Invalid request, task hours is Required."
            key = new_task.put()
            out = new_task.to_dict()
            self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
```

I am using curl to test it:

> ```
> curl --data-urlencode "name=clean" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:15080/task
> ```

I know the problem is in the error checking code (all the if else statements) because when I take it out the curl test works fine and the object is added to the ndb database correctly. However, with the error checking code included my curl test does not add the object as it should. Does anyone have an idea why the error checking code is breaking my post statement? Is there a better way to return HTTP error response codes?

Comment: I tried to fix your code formatting, please check if it still reflects your actual code, especially the indentation.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting, it looks much better!

Answer (score 2):

You had some uninitialized variables in the code (`name`, `hours`, maybe `PARENT_KEY`) and also you didn't return after preparing the error response, thus flowing in areas where the code wouldn't work.

I'd suggest re-organizing the error checking code for minimal impact on the functional code (checks should be done as early as possible, to simplify the remaining functional code. Also, I prefer to use the more concise [`webapp2.abort()`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#abort) function (which doesn't need a `return` statement).

Something along these lines:

```
class Task_action(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        # Only allows a JSON, if not, then error
        if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:
            webapp2.abort(406, details="Not Acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type")

        # request must contain a valid task name
        name = self.request.get("task_name")
        if not name:
            webapp2.abort(400, details="Invalid request, task name is Required.")

        # request must contain a valid task hours
        try:
            hours = int(self.request.get("task_hours"))
        except Exception:
            hours = 0
        if not hours:
            webapp2.abort(400, details="Invalid request, task hours is Required.")

        new_task = Task(parent=PARENT_KEY, name=name, hours=hours, id=hours)

        new_task.name = name  # isn't this done by Task() above?
        new_task.hours = hours  # isn't this done by Task() above?
        key = new_task.put()
        out = new_task.to_dict()
        self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
```

Another note: you're specifying the `id` parameter in the `Task()` call, which doesn't work unless you know each Task() entity has a **unique** `hours` value. You may want to let the datastore assign IDs automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I am going to use the webapp2.abort function because it is more concise and taking a second look there are definitely some duplications in my old code :) I wanted to figure out what was causing the issue with the else statements code and noticed that when you use self.response.write('Error - requests must be JSON\n') then suddenly it works. I wonder if python did not not recognize the global variables 'status' and 'status_message!'